# Content or Contents?

Tags: terminology, british-english, writing

I am finalising my PhD thesis introduction and was wondering where the following is correct.

"(Abstract information about physics and chapters 2 and 3). We briefly describe the content of these chapters."

Should it be content of these chapters, or contents of these chapters?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Both are idiomatic, but have very slightly different meanings.

"The *contents*" I would expect to be followed by a list of the items in the book (I don't necessarily mean the title of each chapter: it could be a list of themes). After *content* I would expect a single statement about the content as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the table of contents, use *contents*. Even better, use *table of contents*.

If you're talking about what's in it, use *content*.

Comment: Didn't Colin say that?

Answer (score 0):

Can i ask are you going to describe either content or contents of the chapters within your thesis? If yes then it seems to me it is personal preferance as much as anything. (Choice should be made after considering wich option would convey the more suitable infomation within the set parameters of the request.)

The plural ‘contents’ is usually a countable noun. We thus use it when we can separate the ‘content’ of something into individual items/ themes. (A books table of contents.)

The singular ‘content’ is typically an uncountable noun. Uncountable nouns are terms that refer to something as an undifferentiated whole. So when using it describes something as a whole. (The movie contained graphic content)

But to answer the question directly i would go with content. 
This is a result of the use of the adverb briefly, as it is a shorter task to describe the main substance within said chapters, also listing contents within a single chapter lacks in practicality.

Comment: I decided to go with contents, purely due to the fact that Chapter 2 has multiple themes which needed to be mentioned